# Realstudio (2011 4.2) Date in Milliseconds

Tags: sql-server, realbasic, realstudio

In my project I communicate with a Microsoft SQL-Database where I have a column with DATETIMEs. The date-information in the database is with Milliseconds, that's very important, like `2012-03-03 12:00:00.364`

In Java, for example, it's no problem to read the Date value from the RecordSet with Milliseconds.

In Realbasic when I do something like that `time = rs.IdxField(i).DateValue` the milliseconds are lost, because the Date-Object has a maximum resolution of seconds.

How can I read the SQL-Datetime with milliseconds? What can be an easy way to read it as String and then parse it or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the information in a database and are just reading from your SQL database, I'd recommend subclassing Date, adding a variable for Milliseconds, and then just manually parsing out from the period/etc to get the milliseconds value.

```
dim d as new DateWithMilliseconds
d=rs.IdxField(i).DateValue

////and then however you'd parse out the milliseconds based on the string format
d.milliseconds=NthField(rs.idxField(i).stringvalue,".",2)
```

You could then add other functions for comparing the date subclass to include the milliseconds variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert Statement
Syntax:

select CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 126)

try it.

Tiz